# Rails 3: Should I avoid having a "random" controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, controller, actioncontroller

In my Rails 3.1 controller `ActivitiesController`, I have an action called `random` (i.e. `/activities/random`) that finds a random activity and then just redirects to that activity (the `show` action is what actually renders the activity).

This has worked well for me so far, but now I'm in the process of Ajax-ify the app and I'm starting to feel* that maybe having a separate controller action `random` is a poor design choice.

Is it better design to incorporate the randomization functionality into the `show` action instead?

***Update/clarification:** When adding Ajax functionality, I realize that a `views/activities/random.js` becomes identical to a `views/activities/show.js`. After all, from a rendering standpoint the two actions are identical, with the only difference being that `:id => 'random'`.

Comment: Personally, I would probably keep these as separate controller actions... to keep the "random" logic separate from the "view" logic.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I initially felt too. But how would you implement it Ajax-style? See my update/clarification above.

Comment: I think your current architecture is fine. You should definitely keep the random/show actions separate.

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's different for your project, but wouldn't your JS files most likely be filed under your `public/javascripts` directory?  If so... aren't your ajax calls going to be going to Rails actions (like "random" and "show"?)  If so... I guess I'm not seeing the problem at present...

Comment: @summea: the .js files I mention are the JavaScript actions/views (that used to be called .rjs in older Rails). My application-wide JavaScript files are of course in assets/javascripts.

Comment: So after reading your update above (as well) are you mostly trying to decide on the best way to not repeat yourself with those two JavaScript actions?

Comment: This is too much thinking. Do what ever you want unless you make sure that you never repeat yourself.